# PC requires me to choose boot device to load Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios

Issue been driving me nuts for a while now.

I'm not sure when exactly this started but I believe it first started when I upgraded to Windows 10 rc a few years ago. If I start my PC it eventually stops with a bios /bootup message "Reboot & Select Proper Boot Device or insert boot media in selected boot device." I have two hard drives in my pc.

To boot into windows, during boot I press F12 to get the boot menu to pop-up where I can then select the device (p1 - WDC) and it boots fine.

Some info --->
Looking in Windows under Disk Management:

1.
Harddrive - ST325
Disk 0: two partitions. First is some small 24mb allocated and then a second partition D: (page file, archive primary partition)

2. Harddrive -

Disk 1: Four partitions. first is 14gb recovery partition. Second, 100mb System Reserved (system, active, primary partition). Third C:\ (boot, crash dump, primary partition). Windows is on this partition. Fourth D:\logical drive storing files

If I look in the BIOS disk drive hard drive priority I have
P1. WPC
P2. ST 325.

So why if I choose P1 WPC from the boot menu it loads windows but if I let it boot by itself where it should be loading the same WPC it won't load windows?

Comment: In Bios boot configuration which one is default booting device.

Comment: The default or 1 option is the WDC drive which is the same one I choose when I press the f12 to get the boot menu manually.

Comment: Did you try by only connecting the OS drive? If not try once and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why I didn't try this earlier, but I just opened the pc and change the sata cables around so that the WD was p0 and the ST325 was P1.  Now boots like it should without any interaction.